# How can I add sample weights to my Keras generator when I don't have a "y" output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to train a [pre-trained model](https://github.com/ymcui/Chinese-BERT-wwm) in Python 3.8 with Keras 2.3.1 and Tensorflow 2.2.3. Since my dataset is very large, I have to use a data generator. I want to assign sample weights to each sample, to make certain samples more important than others. I've already defined the weights that I want to assign to each sample, but I'm looking for a way to implement them in my training. Here's my custom data generator with the code that I've tried so far:

```
   def __iter__(self):
       batch_token_ids, batch_segment_ids = [], []
       sample_weights = np.ones(batch_size)
          for file in dataset:
              for sample in file:

                  # Read the input, output, and sample weight from the dataset.
                  inputs, outputs, weight = get_data(sample)

                  # Encode the input and output using a tokenizer.
                  token_ids, segment_ids = tokenizer.encode(inputs, outputs, maxlen=maxlen)
                  batch_token_ids.append(token_ids)
                  batch_segment_ids.append(segment_ids)

                  # Add the weight to a np array (sample_weights)
                  sample_weights[len(batch_token_ids)-1] = weight

                  # Yield after getting batch_size samples.
                  if len(batch_token_ids) == self.batch_size:
                      """
                      The input format that my model supports is the token and segment ids in x, 
                      with None as the value for y. Changing it raises an error.
                      """
                      yield [batch_token_ids, batch_segment_ids], None, sample_weights
                      batch_token_ids, batch_segment_ids = [], []
                      sample_weights = np.ones(batch_size)
```

According to the Keras documentation, I'm supposed to input the sample weights as the third value that the generator returns. However, I noticed that nothing changed in the training after implementing this. After doing some debugging into what happens to the sample weights after yielding, I noticed that the weights never get used when I try this, because of this code here in training.py of the Keras engine: (line 655)

```
if y is not None:
    # Long code to process the inputs and sample weights.
    # Since I don't have a y input, this doesn't get run.
else:
    y = []
    sample_weights = []
```

Is there a way to implement sample weights for my code without changing the input format? Also, if I'm using a custom loss function, would I need to change that as well for the sample weights to take effect?